# Using Weblogic with Active Directory. Users and Groupes must be in the same Unit Group?

Tags: active-directory, weblogic, authenticator

I'm using Active Directory to authenticate users into an application.
When i put users and groups under the same Organizational Unit the authentication is OK, even permissions (i assign users to Groups) .

The problem is when i put the Groups (the permissions) under a different Organisational Unit, wich is not the same OU where i put the users : We can see the permissions on the Weblogic administrative console, but in the application users have not access to the required functionalities (permissions) .

Configuration : 
 + Weblogic 10.3.3.0 with Custom Authenticator;
 + Active Directory 2008.

Comment: Do you have a custom provider set up in your security realm to pull out the users?

Comment: Yes, i created a custum AD_authenticator . for users i indicate the first Organizational unit, and for groups i indicate an other (The two OU are separete, they do not have teh same parent) . tx